# Merge two arrays with selected name=>value

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have the following multidimensional array:

```
$record = Array(
  Array("name" => "Sheila", "exam1" => "90", "exam2" => "80", "exam3" => "85"),
  Array("name" => "Peter", "exam1" => "80", "exam2" => "95", "exam3" => "85"),
  Array("name" => "Konrad", "exam1" => "98", "exam2" => "70", "exam3" => "89") 
);
```

I have been using the following code,

```
 foreach ( $record as $student ) {
    // store exam # 1 
    foreach ( $student as  $name => $value ) {
       if ( $name == "name") {
          $name = Array ($name => $value);
       }

       if ( $name == "exam1") {
          $grade = Array ($name => $value);
       }        
    }
 }
```

but it when I merge these two, I do not get my desired output which is (basically storing the name with its corresponding grade):

```
 $exam1 = Array( 
  Array("name" => "Sheila", "exam1" => "90"),
  Array("name" => "Peter", "exam1" => "80"),
  Array("name" => "Konrad", "exam1" => "98")
 );
```

How do I get the array I want?

Comment: Are you also needing exam2, exam3? There is no need for the inner loop since you can just access by key `$exam1[] = array('name'=>$student['name'], 'exam1'=>$student['exam1']);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$data = array();
foreach($students as $record) {
  $data[] = array('name' => $record['name'], 'exam1' => $record['exam1']);
}
```

Or you could use a fancier (and easier to extend) version:

```
<?php
$students = Array(
  Array("name" => "Sheila", "exam1" => "90", "exam2" => "80", "exam3" => "85"),
  Array("name" => "Peter", "exam1" => "80", "exam2" => "95", "exam3" => "85"),
  Array("name" => "Konrad", "exam1" => "98", "exam2" => "70", "exam3" => "89") 
);

$desired_metadata = array('name', 'exam1');
$data = array();
$flip = array_flip($desired_metadata);
foreach($students as $record) {
    $data[] = array_combine($desired_metadata, array_intersect_key($flip, $record));
}

var_dump($data);
```